# Catch Dynamic ID from jQuery

Tags: jquery

Cannot catch the dynamic id, following code explain you all

**HTML**

```
 <select id="dropDown" class="dropDown">
                <option value="Red Car">Car</option>
                <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
 </select>

 <div  id="Red Car"><div/>
 <div  id="Bus"><div/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#dropDown").click(function () {
    var selectedOption = $('#dropDown').find('option:selected').text();
    $("#" + selectedOption).css({ "display": "none" });        
});
```

any of div is not getting the applied (display : none) !

Comment: yea.. "change" instead of"click" working fine, but if 'id' is of two words, then? ex - "Red Car" rather than "Car".. then what will be the case?

Comment: or three, or multiple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).on('change', '#dropDown', function(){

    $('#' + $('#dropDown').val()).hide();

});
```

Comment: if spaces are at unknown places, Ex- "hey! I have a blue car" then what say?

Comment: This method takes the `value` value from the select box, not the text. for example:  `<option value="blue_car">Blue Car</option>`. ID attributes shouldn't generally have spaces. So in the example above, if you select 'Blue Car', the function will retrieve the value attribute from the option element, which is `blue_car`

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/N48hf/

Use `change()` instead of `click()`

```
$("#dropDown").change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $('#dropDown').find('option:selected').text();
    $("#" + selectedOption).hide();        
});
```

EDIT: According to the update to the question

Your ids have spaces, so, use the selector like this `$("[id='ID WITH SPACES']"`

http://jsfiddle.net/N48hf/3/

```
$("#dropDown").change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $('#dropDown').val();
    $('div').show();
    $("[id='" + selectedOption +"']").hide();        
});
```

Comment: yea.. that's working, but if 'id' is of two words, then? see the question

Comment: yea that's working too, but if the spaces are in perforated manner, at unknown placed and unknown number of times.. Ex- "hey! I have a blue car" then what say?

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` working [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/7FUBn/1/)

```
$("#dropDown").on("change", function () {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $("#" + selectedOption).css({ "display": "none" });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use .val() instead of the text like [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wne3n/)

```
$("#dropDown").on('change', function () {
    $("#" + $('#dropDown').val()).css({ "display": "none" });        
});
```